# How to merge 'already merged' revisions?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I've merged a few revisions from one branch to the trunk and committed them. Then I've found there was an issue with this merge so I've reverted it back and committed the revert.

Now after I've fixed everything I want to merge these revisions again. But Tortoise doesn't let me do this, it says "already merged" and doesn't want to apply files to the local copy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it allow you to if you check *Force the merge*?

Comment: Yes, it added 'Recodring mergeinfo for merge' but no files are really changed.

Comment: Can you please check the log of the revision in which you committed the reverted changes and verity if you also committed changes to the *svn:mergeinfo* property in the top-level folder?

Comment: Seems like the top-level folder wasn't committed during revert for some reason. Also, it's not listed in locally changed files. What should I do in this situation? Can I force-commit it somehow?

Comment: You can try editing the property manually and removing the revisions involved from the list. It's possible (I'm not fully sure though) that you don't need to commit before you can merge.

Comment: Yes, manual editing helped. I would mark your answer as accepted, though I can't since it's a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subversion merge tracking is not particularly sophisticated. You just get a versioned property called `svn:mergeinfo` in the top-level directory where you apply merges that looks like this:

[image: Edit Properties dialog]

You possibly forgot to revert the property change (you can verify that in the *SVN Show log* dialog).

You may be able to fix it by reverting the property change from e.g. the log (right click and *Revert changes from this revision*) but, if the GUI gets on the way, you can also edit the property yourself:

[image: Properties context menu]